# Ubuntu не находит пакеты

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, maven

У меня на виртуальной машине стоит Ubuntu версии 18.04. При загрузке некоторых пакетов, например `libmysql-java` и `maven` пишется, что пакет не найден. В случае с `maven` ввожу `mvn`, мне предлагает загрузить его, копирую команду и пишет, что пакет не найден. Ни `apt`, ни `apt-get` не проходит.

```
user@server:~$ mvn -version

Command 'mvn' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install maven

user@server:~$ sudo apt install maven
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет maven
```

Comment: Maven обычно устанавливают простой распаковкой архива и добавлением поддиректории `bin` в переменную окружения `PATH`. Опционально можно ещё объявить необязательную переменную окружения `M2_HOME`, помогающую IntelliJ найти место распаковки Maven. Таким же образом обычно устанавливают и JDK. Не представляют зачем из этого делать Linux пакеты или устанавливать именно из пакетов.

Comment: `$ sudo apt update`

Comment: maven уже поставляется с идеей. или вам нравится запускать проекты через терминал?

Answer (score 1):

Этот пакет [есть](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/maven) в репах Ubuntu 18.04. Если совет с обновлением кэша не помог, смотрите что вы там накрутили со списком репозиториев. Смотреть здесь:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```